# Converting octal to binary

Tags: haskell, functional-programming

one of the things I have to do in my Haskell homework is to write a function that converts an octal number to a binary number, the things is that it is specifically asked that the input must be a string.

I figured I would write it like this:

```
okt2bin:: String -> String
okt2bin n     
       |n == "0" = "000"
       |n == "1" = "001"
       |n == "2" = "010"
       |n == "3" = "011"
       |n == "4" = "100"
       |n == "5" = "101"
       |n == "6" = "110"
       |n == "7" = "111"
```

The thing is, I can't get it to work for multiple digit numbers. Can anyone help?

Comment: I think your function should be of type `Char -> String`. Then use it as the base function in a `map`.

Comment: `okts2bins = concatMap (okt2bin.show)`

Comment: Another suggestion, use pattern matching instead of guards, and one thing more, you have not considered negative inputs.(Might not be needed in exercise, but why not go above and beyond :))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can write a function for a single digit, which pretty much looks the same:

```
octDigit2Bin :: Char -> String
octDigit2Bin n
       |n == '0' = "000"
       |n == '1' = "001"
       |n == '2' = "010"
       |n == '3' = "011"
       |n == '4' = "100"
       |n == '5' = "101"
       |n == '6' = "110"
       |n == '7' = "111"
```

Afterwards you can use the nice property that you can transform a multi-digit octal number into a binary one by transforming each digit, since `8` is a power of `2`, e.g. "75" can be transformed by transforming '7' into "111" and '5' into "101" and therefore "75" is "111101":

```
okt2bin :: String -> String
okt2bin xs = concatMap octDigit2Bin xs
```

Comment: Thank you, doing that helped.

Answer (score 0):

There is functions for dealing with different integer encodings in the module 'Numeric', which is part of 'base'.

Since it's for homework, I'm guessing the intention was for you to calculate the binary representation and be able to convert an arbitrary octal encoded integer.